# rails redirect from child create to child show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am sure there is a solution for this but I am not seeing it. I want to redirect to the show page for my child after creation.

I have just created a child record for my parent record in my child controller like so:

```
def create
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comment = article.comments.create(comment_params)
   redirect_to "/articles/#{@article.id}/comments/#{@comment.id}"
end

...
private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
```

I would like to do something like `redirect_to @comment`

Is there a way to do this? Once I did the above I also got an error with this prebaked code from the scaffold creation:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(@comment) %>
```

I feel like there is something wrong with my routes maybe or I am not referencing the path for my child correctly.

routes.rb:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

1. How do I redirect to the "show" of my child correctly in the create method of my controller
2. Why would my edit path be broken in my child show view?

thanks

Comment: share your `rake routes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

## controller

```
def create
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comment = article.comments.create(comment_params)
   redirect_to article_comment_path(@article,@comment)
end
```

## view

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_comment_path(@article, @comment) %>
```

## routes

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

Comment: You can also use `redirect_to [@article, @comment]`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that there seems to be a small typo:

1. in the second line it should be `@article`, not `article`.
2. the second line could also be:

   ```
   @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
   ```

so this would also work:

```
def create
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
   redirect_to article_comment_path(@article,@comment)
end
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32631801)